# Command line option to tell msi installation to a specific location

Tags: asp.net, configuration, command-line, windows-installer

Is there anyway to install the msi at specific location through the command line.

Comment: Is this a Web project? If so, there is no simple way but some workarounds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, typically, you can specify a `TARGETDIR=(path to install to)` when you run the `msiexec` installer:

```
msiexec /i (yourFile).msi TARGETDIR=C:\YourBin\YourApp
```

I've been corrected (thanks to **0xA3** for this!) - my initial mention of `INSTALLDIR` is wrong - you need to use `TARGETDIR` instead. That one does indeed seem to work for just about any MSI I tried it on. Windows Installer stuff isn't exactly intuitive or easy......

Comment: Afaik, INSTALLDIR is only defined in InstallShield .msi files. Usually the property would be named TARGETDIR (see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winformssetup/thread/1997d0ae-4b67-4453-881d-7e176c372a67)

Comment: @0xA3: thanks for the heads up! I have been using INSTALLDIR in WiX projects, too - but you're right: run of the mill MSI's don't seem to respond to that :-( But TARGETDIR= works like a charm!

Comment: I also got corrected on the same mistake here on SO some time ago ;-)

Answer (score 4):

If this is a Web setup, you can use the workaround described [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/47153558-b60c-426a-8036-0fa746fbf977). Otherwise you may specify the MSI property [`TARGETDIR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372064%28VS.85%29.aspx) on the command line:

```
msiexec /i setup.msi TARGETDIR="C:\TestLocation\"
```